# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: 16.04, mysql, configuration

I am unable to start my MySQL server 5.7 running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. System is on a virtual box being hosted on a Windows 10 x64 machine. I have 4GB of memory allocated and 2 cores.

I can not get the MySQL server to start and my best guess is that I need to edit and/or possibly move copies of the MySQL my.cnf files as part of the installation/set-up.

The below instructions from file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` refers to a directory for user-specific options, but I am not clear as to what user-specific directory to copy.

You can copy this to one of:

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to set global options,

`~/.my.cnf` to set user-specific options.

I am not signed into the OS as the admin but as myself per the guide I used for the initial set-up. Also, I am obviously new to Linux and the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out of the box, if you have installed it via apt-get. Have you run the function "mysql_secure_installation", to setup and secure your installation?

Also you should ensure, that the MySQL server is running.

Try to run 
$: sudo service mysql start